# Nullable<> types are a BCL, CLR, or both implementation?

Tags: c#, clr, nullable, base-class-library

Some time ago I thought that Nullable<> value types are classes, encapsulating value types and a bool to HasValue. With some implicit cast operador for null, just implemented at BCL.

But being a struct, how this can be achieved? Nullable<> struct is "special" for CLR?

Comment: `Nullable` is a static class that works with `Nullable<T>` struct objects (in case of any confusion).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` is defined as a normal struct, but there's special hooks within the CLR to box/unbox an instance of `` [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1 `` to null according to the `HasValue` property. There's more details on this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2005/08/11/450640.aspx)

Comment: Interesting piece.  I personally dislike the idea that one should expect to test for empty nullables by testing for null; in the absence of such expectation, it would be possible to have something like `Dictionary.TryGetValue` return a `T?` regardless of whether `T` was a class or referenced type.  If a key exists and its value is `null`, the returned item would have `HasValue` report true and `Value` report null.  As it is, there's no generic constraint that implies a type supports null, and thus no efficient way to test for nullity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the MSDN article on Nullable Types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=VS.100).aspx

I'm not sure what you're trying to get at with Nullable<>, unless you're mis-understanding that Nullable types are instances of the `System.Nullable<T>` struct.

Answer (score 0):

`Nullable<>` is a struct implemented within mscorlib.

One special thing is in the C# compiler that recognizes `X?` as an alias for `Nullable<X>`.