# Why is Nullable type supported by CLR?

Tags: c#, clr

I heard that the addition of `Nullable<T>` type to C# 2.0 need to revise CLR(runtime) a little, is this change necessary? Could it make the same goal if a new `Nullable<T>` generic class was added only?

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2005/08/11/450640.aspx

Comment: also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694264/nullable-types-are-a-bcl-clr-or-both-implementation

Comment: Boxing conversions are implemented by the CLR.  Nullable<> has an unusual boxing conversion.  And thus required unusual code in the CLR.

Comment: @Hans: Do you know of any other areas of the CLR -- as opposed to the C# compiler etc -- where nullables are special-cased? The only other one that I can think of is the `where T : struct` generic constraint.

Comment: @Luke - there's lots.  Best thing to do is search the SSCLI20 clr/src/vm directory for "nullable".

Comment: @Hans: Thanks, lots of stuff there, most of it over my head. To my untrained eye it looks like most (all?) of it is "infrastructure" stuff needed to support nullables in general, rather than anything with outwardly observable side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nullable` isn't a generic class as you indicate, `Nullable<T>` is generic (it has a type parameter, `T`).  That's why `Nullable<T>` only arrived in C# 2.0: it came with the addition of generics to the CLR.

You could do the same thing with a general `Nullable`, but you couldn't do things like this:

```
int? myInt = 123;
int result = myInt.Value;
```

You would instead have to:

```
int result = (int)myInt.Value;
```

...and it might not be type-safe, by that I mean what if `myInt.Value` is a `string`?  The generic version, `Nullable<T>`, would only allow an `int` into the `Value` property.

I don't completely understand what you're asking, though.. "why are generic classes useful"?

Comment: I just wondering why the runtime need to be changed to get `Nullable<T>` to work. For example, can get all the same behavior as `Nullable<int>` if I copy all its definition and rename it to `Nullable1<T>`?

Comment: Before C# 2.0, there were no generics - and so you couldn't have a generic class like `Nullable<T>`.  Unless you have some other information or reference?  You could create your own `Nullable1<T>`, certainly

Comment: Thanks. I mean to add `Nullable1<T>` in C# 2.0 or later, but would it get the same behavior as the CLR defined one?

Comment: Not quite the same. The Nullable in the CLR is value type and what you will create is going to be reference type, and if you create it as value type then you won't be able to assign it to null value because by definition value type is non nullable.

Comment: @Fadrian: Your comment is slightly misleading: The question asks about the CLR and the CLR *does not* allow you to assign null to any value-type, even nullables. The C# compiler *does* allow you to assign null to nullables, but behind-the-scenes that just gets translated into zero-initialisation of the value-type. (Having said that, there is nullable-specific logic in the CLR. For example, the boxing and unboxing of nullables is special-cased, as is the `where T : struct` generic constraint.)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking why can't it just be Type introduced in the framework library? but instead the CLR need to be changed?

Well based on my understanding Nullable is a special type, not quite like other container type. First it is actually a value type - defined as struct, not a class. Separately it allows to be assigned a value of null (for value type, that is a special case), plus it support the use of '?' and operator '??' which is all new. The Nullable also become part of the Common type system. So I guess from these perspective, the specification, compiler and CLR will need to be changed.

Comment: Yes, you got my question. I just wonder whether pure definition in the framework library could get the whole job done.

Comment: No, see my comment on Kieren answer.

Comment: @Fadrian: The "tricks" you're describing here are all performed by the C# compiler, not the CLR. (The CLR does, however, support nullables with special behaviour related to boxing/unboxing and generic constraints.)

Answer (score 0):

There are only two reasons I know of for the special handling of Nullable<T>:

1. To allow a typecast from null Object reference to a Nullable<T> with HasValue = false.

   To allow a Nullable<T> where HasValue is false, to compare equal to null.

Frankly, think it would have been better to let Nullable<T> box like any other value type, and define Nullable<T>.Empty as a value which may be compared against (for those cases where one might want to compare against a variable that might be null or might hold a value).  To my mind, there's no reason why Object.Equals should report that an "int?" which is equal to null is equal to a "long?" which is also equal to null.  The first should be viewed as an empty int-sized box, and the latter as an empty long-sized box.